# Не отображается RecyclerView при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

На одной из активностей есть `RecyclerView`. При создании адаптера возникают некоторые проблемы. После запуска активности, элементов `RecyclerView` не видно, хотя по отладке все вроде должно работать.

Код Адаптера:

```
class ResultViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Recept> recepts;

ResultViewAdapter(Context context, List<Recept> recepts) {
    this.recepts = recepts;
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public ResultViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ResultViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Recept recept = recepts.get(position);
    //holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
    holder.nameView.setText(recept.getName());
    holder.discrView.setText(recept.getIngridients());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recepts.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView nameView, discrView;
    final CardView cv;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
       // imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        discrView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.discr);
        cv = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    }
}
}
```

Код класса Recept:

```
public class Recept {
String name,discription;
String ingridients;
public Recept(String name, String discription, String ingridients){
    this.name = name;
    this.discription = discription;
    this.ingridients = ingridients;
}
public Recept(String name,String ingridients){
    this.name = name;
    this.ingridients = ingridients;
}

public String getIngridients() {

    return ingridients;
}

public void setIngridients(String ingridients) {
    this.ingridients = ingridients;
}

public String getDiscription() {
    return discription;
}

public void setDiscription(String discription) {
    this.discription = discription;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Фрагмент кода активности:

```
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    List<Recept> list_test = new ArrayList<Recept>();
    list_test.add(new Recept("test","Disc"));
    ResultViewAdapter adapter1 = new ResultViewAdapter(ResultActivity.this, list_test);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте LayoutManager, без него RecyclerView не отображается.

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
или
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this,4); 
и
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm); или recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

Comment: Вау. Спасибо, работает.